# PowerShell DataGridView checkbox row cell value

Tags: winforms, powershell, datagridview

This is the function to check if checkbox is true winforms DataGridView:

```
function Install {
    param (
        # OptionalParameters
    )
    
    for($i=0;$i -lt $getAppsDataGrid.RowCount;$i++){ 

        if($getAppsDataGrid.Rows[$i].Cells[3].Value -eq $true)
        {
            $i
            $getAppsDataGrid.Rows[$i].Cells[$i].Value
            write-host "cell #$i is checked"
          

          #uncheck it
          #$datagridview1.Rows[$i].Cells['exp'].Value=$false
        }
        else    
        {
          #check it
          #$datagridview1.Rows[$i].Cells['exp'].Value=$true
          write-host  "cell #$i is not-checked"

        }
    }
}
```

This is working so far. But I want the cell value from the current row. `$getAppsDataGrid.Rows[$i].Cells[1].Value` is not working in this function. But outside of this function it works. Also other things dont show in here like current var `$i`. Everything except "cell $i is checked / not checked is" irgnored

Output:

```
cell #0 is checked
cell #1 is checked
cell #2 is checked
cell #3 is not-checked
cell #4 is not-checked
cell #5 is not-checked
cell #6 is not-checked
cell #7 is not-checked
cell #8 is not-checked
cell #9 is not-checked
cell #10 is not-checked
cell #11 is not-checked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between writing something to host and writing it in output (or returning it from function).

When you use `Write-output $i` or `return $i` or `$i` you are adding $i to the output stream, or result of the function. When calling the function if you capture the result in a variable, then the outputs will not print.

Look at this example:

```
function GetEvens {  
    for($i=0;$i -lt 10;$i++){ 

        if($i%2 -eq 0)
        {
            $i
            write-host "#$i is even"
        }
        else    
        {
          write-host "#$i is odd"
        }
    }
}

$evens = GetEvens
```

It captures the output (return values) which are even numbers in $evens but write the string "#i is odd" or "#i is even" in host.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function, you are simply dumping `$i` and `$getAppsDataGrid.Rows[$i].Cells[1].Value` through down the pipeline, showing nothing in the console.

To write to console, use the `Write-*` cmdlets. This is why strings like `cell #0 is checked` DO show up in the console.

If you want your function to write out everything to the console, change it to something like

```
function Install {
    param (
        # OptionalParameters
    )

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $getAppsDataGrid.RowCount; $i++){ 
        Write-Host "Checking row $i"
        if($getAppsDataGrid.Rows[$i].Cells[3].Value) {
            Write-Host "Value ($i,$i): {0}" -f $getAppsDataGrid.Rows[$i].Cells[$i].Value
            Write-Host "cell #$i is checked"

            #uncheck it
            #$datagridview1.Rows[$i].Cells['exp'].Value=$false
        }
        else {
          #check it
          #$datagridview1.Rows[$i].Cells['exp'].Value=$true
          Write-Host  "cell #$i is not-checked"
        }
    }
}
```